# Downsizing the "FALSE" (0's) events to get more more accurate predictions

Tags: regression, classification, binary-data

I am working on a data-set with binary response and the number of TRUE events in the data is <6%. But the occurrence of the TRUE is ~10%.

The accuracy of my model is low and based on the classification table, it looks like its under-predicting the TRUE's.

Is downsizing the FALSE events in the data to match the real life scenario of an acceptable practice i.e. is sampling the FALSE events to maintain a 1:9 ratio TRUE: FALSE an option or will it introduce bias in the model?

I am sorry, i didn't frame my question well. What i meant to convey is that in the data that i have only 6% of them are TRUE/1's. And the data is from a real time source. But under actual conditions the rate of 1's should be ~10% or more. So the data that i have has not been sampled well to represent the true population. What i have is a data subset that is skewed towards the FALSE's

Answer (score 1):

If you really just have a different covariate distribution than in another population, then I am not sure you need to do anything. If your data does not match up with the situation you are interested in in other ways, then I would be very worried that the data is also unrepresentative in other ways (e.g. covariate to outcome relationships).

Comment: No, the covariates are not the problem. Its just that the rate of the true positive is slightly greater than half of what can be seen in the real life data. So my model is classifying certain true positives as true negatives since the data is skewed towards the false events.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that there are unexplainable differences? If so, it is hard to know how useful the data you have is for predicting things, when it is unclear why there is such a huge difference.

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't frame my question well. What i meant to convey is that in the data that i have only 6% of them are TRUE/1's. And the data is from a real time source. But under actual conditions the rate of 1's should be ~10% or more. So the data that i have has not been sampled well to represent the true population. What i have is a data subset that i skewed towards the FALSE's.